Explain the difference between the two approaches to invoking asynchronous operations
I have two variations of the code that will be provided below.
The task of the code is as follows: I have two URLs that I make an HTTP Get request on, and I want to get content from there.
In the first case, I use Task.WhenAll and pass two asynchronous method calls, expecting my tasks to execute in parallel and in different threads.
But judging by the output, all of them are executed in the main thread, its id = 1.
In the second case, I use await and expect my tasks to execute sequentially but concurrently.
Although, the very essence of await is to wait for an operation to be executed without blocking the main thread.
Please explain where I am mistaken and which option is preferable for such a task?
Method (same in both cases)
public static async Task<string> FetchDataFromUrl(string url)
{
    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            return await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

Call of method No. 1
string url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
string url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1";


var results = await Task.WhenAll(FetchDataFromUrl(url1), FetchDataFromUrl(url2));

Call of method No. 2
string url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
string url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1";

List<string> results = new List<string>
            {
                await FetchDataFromUrl(url1),
                await FetchDataFromUrl(url2),
            };


Related: Difference between await Task and await Task.WhenAll. Also this: Multiple awaits vs Task.WaitAll - equivalent?

"In the second case, I use await and expect my tasks to execute sequentially but concurrently." -- The terms sequential and concurrent are pretty much antithetical. Could you elaborate what you mean?

"But judging by the output, all of them are executed in the main thread, its id = 1." - id of "current" thread is captured before any async handling happens, so it can't support your claim (and you don't block current thread, so it "skips" to the second call). Write thread id to output  before and after GetStringAsync call.

Also dont create a new HttpClient for every request. When you dispose each client, you force all tcp connections to close. Which might be fine for 2 parallel requests, but not 200.

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

As mentioned by @GuruStron

Write thread id to output before and after GetStringAsync

so Add some Diagnoses code to know what happen there
async Task<string> FetchDataFromUrl(string url)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"FetchDataFromUrl start run on ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,2}");
    try
    {
        using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Console.WriteLine($"task start  on Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,2},\t Get {url}");
        var result = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url));
        Console.WriteLine($"task return on Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,2},\t Don {url}");

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

and Run the following Program
string url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
string url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1";

Console.WriteLine($"Main on Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
var results = await Task.WhenAll(FetchDataFromUrl(url1), FetchDataFromUrl(url2));
Console.WriteLine($"Main return on Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

Console.WriteLine("\n==========================\n");

Console.WriteLine($"Main on Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
List<string> results2 = new List<string>
            {
                await FetchDataFromUrl(url1),
                await FetchDataFromUrl(url2),
            };
Console.WriteLine($"Main return on Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

the output in my computer is look like the following
Main on Id: 1
FetchDataFromUrl start run on ID:  1
task start  on Id:  1,   Get https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
FetchDataFromUrl start run on ID:  1
task start  on Id:  1,   Get https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1
task return on Id:  7,   Don https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1
task return on Id: 11,   Don https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
Main return on Id: 11

==========================

Main on Id: 11
FetchDataFromUrl start run on ID: 11
task start  on Id: 11,   Get https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
task return on Id:  7,   Don https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
FetchDataFromUrl start run on ID:  7
task start  on Id:  7,   Get https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1
task return on Id:  5,   Don https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1
Main return on Id: 5

you can Interpret it as graphically as following

the Most Important thing to Note that there is NO Parallel code at all in both cases
I Recommend you to read the following

Asynchronous programming with async and await
What is the difference between concurrency and parallelism?



well, copying from my answer without giving credit.
You should have run things separately. and not let things with threads get confusing because of the state machine in Main



The graph is wrong. The start is done on Main Thread


I also recommend you reading How Async/Await Really Works in C# by Stephen Toub

@Ivan Petrov I did not copy anything from you !!! The idea is mentioned by  Guru Strong in the comments .... I mix both of them to give the OP the idea of what happen!! ... then what is your interpretation to the graph !! When you use Async, the context could be switch to other worker threads !! There is no guarantee that you will return on the same thread

I didn't see you give credit to him either. When you write an answer you can check if the same thing isn't already mentioned in the already available answer.

also it's a bit of immature to delete comments to which you demanded a response.

@lvan thanks for your recommendation I will read it now to know what you mean

would be glad to have assisted you on your path of better understanding. Cheers!

@IvanPetrov it's not required to give credit to a comment under the question, for the simple reason that the comments under the question are not intended for answering the question. Whoever does that violates the rules of the site, and we shouldn't give credit to people who violate the rules of the site.

@TheodorZoulias You're required to give credit to any non-trivial content you're copying, regardless of the source.  Even if you feel some content should not have been a comment, copying it without credit is both plagiarism and also a violation of copyright, assuming the content in question isn't trivial.  (Note I don't see evidence anything in this answer was copied and not a solution arrived at independently.)

@TheodorZoulias you can see that the second version of my answer with the Console.WriteLine statements appeared on 07.02 23:58:00Z, this answer makes use of this in an edit at 07 03 01:24:00Z which is 90 minutes later.

@IvanPetrov If I take anything from you, I will say that directly ... and the code I take it from the OP and I change it, then guess what I have use Console.Writeline as normal output string instead of async output use by the OP ... and for the god sake stop saying that I take anything from you ... even I did not continuo read you answer after I see you mention parallel execution in Asynchronous Code

@Servy is this your personal opinion or a rule of the site? No offence but I don't care about your opinion, because I have my own. I am not going to give credit to anyone who violates the rules of the site by trying to answer the question in the comments.

@TheodorZoulias The question of copyright is a legal one, and has nothing to do with any rules of any sites anywhere.  Someone posting a content is not giving you the right to freely copy their content.  By posting it to this site they are giving you a CC license to copy it with attribution though.  Meaning to not attribute it would require it being not copyrightable content or it being fair use.

It being plagiarism is even less clear cut as far as what kind of content qualifies as being something that requires attribution and what is "common knowledge" or "novel" or whatever.  But while different people draw the line at what kind of content requires attribution at different places, where you copy it from is irrelevant in pretty much any definition, including the the SO specific definition (https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) which has no "but you can copy comments without attribution" clause.

@Servy according to the help center "comments are temporary 'Post-It' notes left on a question or answer.". Temporary means that they can be deleted. "There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good." If anyone sues me for not giving credit to their comment, I'll flag their comment for violating the rules of the site, and my flag will likely be accepted (I have 2 accepted flags this month alone, for this specific reason). So good luck suing me. No credit to site-rules violators from me.

@TheodorZoulias Your assertion that you don't care about violating copyright and that you fully intent to plagiarize content, purely because you believe you won't get caught is certainly an opinion you're allowed to hold.  But just because you personally are willing to violate the law and the rules of the site in the hopes that you will get away with it doesn't make it okay to tell others that it's acceptable or that it isn't plagiarism.  It is, unequivocally, you just don't care.  I can't make you care, but I can tell other people that it's not okay to plagiarize comments.

And just for your information, comments are not deleted ever (a small number of rare exceptions exist, this hypothetical wouldn't qualify), merely hidden.  If you're violating a user's copyright and they sue, the comment still exists, and SO can provide that information on request.  Likewise, if your content is flagged for plagiarism a user can refer to a deleted comment and a moderator can see that and respond to your plagiarism accordingly.  If you feel a comment violates the rules flagging it and hoping for deletion is fine.  Plagiarizing it is not.

@Servy if someone sues me for not giving credit to their comment, my responce will be that I cannot give credit to content that is not publicly visible, nor I can give credit to content that is subject to deletion according to the site policies. I find it amusing that you question my ethics, because I refuse to give credit to people whose moral ground is the bottom of the barrel. I am gladly giving credit to authors who post their answers  properly as answers. I've done it many times, and I'll continue doing so. But rewarding bad behaviors is not my style.

@TheodorZoulias You can in fact give credit to deleted content.  That you don't want to  doesn't mean you can't.  Likewise you're perfectly capable of citing content that could potentially be deleted in the future (as that is all content).  I find it amusing that you think demanding your right to plagiarize and illegally copy content makes you morally superior.  It's genuinely hilarious to me.  If you don't want to give credit to someone then don't use their content and you won't have to cite them.  That you don't like someone doesn't give you the right to plagiarize them.

@Servy let's be more specific (and less emotional, myself included). There is a comment under this question suggesting to log the thread Id after awaiting the asynchronous operation. This is a good suggestion, but is also a suggestion that anyone could come up independently, without reading the comment. Is everyone morally or legally obligated to credit the author of that comment if they offer the same suggestion in their answer, that they posted later? Note that they are not going to copy/paste the original comment verbatim. They are only resurfacing the same idea. What do you think?

@TheodorZoulias To quote my own first comment, "(Note I don't see evidence anything in this answer was copied and not a solution arrived at independently." Of course the answer has been edited since, but that was true at the time I said it.

@Servy yes, but was the author of this answer morally/legally obligated to credit the author of that comment? To put it in another way, would you have downvoted this answer if credit wasn't given?

@TheodorZoulias My impression was that this answerer didn't even see that comment, and that it wasn't copied, but two people independently coming up with a debugging strategy that is such a common (and trivial) debugging strategy that I wouldn't consider it something anyone can "own", and thus wouldn't require attribution whenever anyone uses it regardless.  Personally I think citing something so simple detracts from the answer, rather than adding to it (I don't feel strongly enough to remove it myself).   But that doesn't apply to all comments.

@Servy well, I have nothing more to add apart from that I agree with your assessment of this specific case.

@IbramReda here are the screenshots (available for most people to verify by looking at the versions). my second edit which is 90 minutes before you posted your first version of the answer. It is line-by-line the same code (with some strings differing)

@TheodorZoulias please see previous comment and verify that it's 1:1 copy-paste from my answer (90 minutes difference).

@IvanPetrov So the only code that's not identical to the code from the question itself is not fact the same.  Sure doesn't seem like plagiarism to me.  Unless you're accusing them of "stealing" the code from the question, but I think it's pretty fair to say that any answer on SO that takes code from the question it's answering and modifies it doesn't need to cite it.  If you think the underlying idea of writing out debugging information to the console is inherently owned by you, and requires citation by others to do, then...let's just say I disagree.

@​Ivan honestly I don't care. I only wanted to share my opinion about not giving credit to answers that are posted under the question as comments.

@Servy I know it's the only logical thing to do in this question and most likely not any plagiarism. It just is not very ethical to explain the exact same thing in the exact same manner that an existing answer did 90 minutes prior. I would cite the other answer and expand if I think they are missing something.

@TheodorZoulias at least we have a correct looking pictures in the answer at this time which is a win in and of itself.

@IvanPetrov The explanations were (and are) pretty radically different.  I see no evidence of plagiarism of the explanations.  They're two independent answers to the question not using the other's content.  And of course neither answers are providing really novel information generally.  Both are (in my opinion, poor) explanations of extremely common and widely described behaviors of asynchrony, and do no need repeating yet again.  This isn't information that you created before anyone else 22 hours ago.

@Servy well we can agree on your last points. Have a good night.

@lvan How the explanation being the same ... my explanation since the beginning is just emphasized that there is no parallelism in this code and I just visualize what is the output as I get it from my computer (even the output was not correct in my opinion, but I write down what I get it because I was trust my code, and then it turns that it have a bug then I fixed it).

@lvan Your answer I stopped read it after this line "both proceed in parallel" ... and then I post my answer to emphasized that there is no parallelism, then you come and saying you copy from me, you copy from me. Then I go and continuo reading your answer, and it turns out you wrote a code that similar to me because both of us take it from OP !!!!!!!! ... if I take anything from you, I would mention it without problem. Man, it is not even worth to lie.
